# Trying to fetch 5 messages and then react to them - discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js, fetch, message

I am trying to get 5 previous messages from a channel and then react to them with discord.js

```
message.channel.messages.fetch(channelID).then(channel => {
            channel.messages.fetch({limit : 5}).then(message => {
                message.react("✅");
            })
        })
```

The error I am getting: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'messages' of undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues within your code (One of them that some seemed to ignore here).

Your first error comes within the following line, stating:

```js
message.channel.messages.fetch(channelID).then(channel => {
```

The `Channel#messages#fetch()` method does not return a Channel object, but a message object. Since you're trying to fetch messages from a **channel** object, you should be fetching a channel rather than a message. Try replacing your line with the following:

```js
client.channels.fetch(channelID).then(channel => { ... }
```

The second issue is that when you're fetching more than one message in Discord.js, the method returns a **collection of objects** rather than an object. Unlike a regular single message object, a collection of message objects does not have a `react()` method property, and it should be split using the `forEach()` iterator to add the reactions separately between each message, as seen below:

```js
client.channels.fetch(channelID).then(channel => {
  channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 5 }).then(messages => {
    messages.forEach(async message => {
      await message.react('✅') // It is recommended to await a reaction method before going on to the next one.
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! You solved my problem!

Comment: @AlexCh No problem!
Would you mind marking my answer as correct so others could find it as useful as well?

Answer (score 0):

Considering you already have a channel as a message property you should do something like this:

```
message.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 5 }).then(message => {
    message.react("✅");
})
```

Comment: hello, thanks for the answer, I am still getting the same error, i have initialized my channel here `let channel = guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.id == <id>);`

Comment: Could you please log the `channel` variable just to see whether it was properly found?

Comment: well, it seems like the channel was found properly. Same for messages. Could you please update the question description, as the code you wrote in the previous comment is pretty different from what you posted in the original issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `MessageManager#fetch()` returns a Collection (Map) of all the fetched messages. You are trying to call `.react()` directly on what is essentially a list of multiple messages. Use `.forEach()` to react to each individual message.

```
message.channel.messages.fetch(channelID).then(channel => {
            channel.messages.fetch({limit : 5}).then(messages => {
                messages.forEach(msg => {
                   msg.react('✅')
                })
            })
       })
```

[Documentation for MessageManager#fetch()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch)